# Ошибка AVLN:0004 Unable to resolve type VideoFile from namespace

Tags: c#, avalonia

Мужики, всем привет. Пытаюсь разобраться с Avalonia, не могу понять что я делаю не так, у меня в main есть класс VideoFile, у которого есть метод FileName

```
public class VideoFile
    {
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public List<string> Output { get; set; }

        public VideoFile(string filePath)
        {
            FilePath = filePath;
            FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            Output = new List<string>();
        }
```

То есть он берет имя файла и его путь, но на путь можно немного забить, он нужен только для выполнения команды, выводить его не нужно, а вот имя файла нужно.

И я вот не могу понять как avalonia объяснить, что имя файла она должна брать из этого класса.

Ошибка  AVLN:0004   Unable to resolve type VideoFile from namespace clr-namespace:avalonvidprocapp, строка 23, позиция 31.
Сама строка

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="local:VideoFile">
```

Собственно вот мой код axaml

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:avalonvidprocapp"
    x:Class="avalonvidprocapp.MainWindow"  
    x:CompileBindings="True"
    Title="Video Processing App" Width="800" Height="450">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button x:Name="SelectFolderButton" Content="Select Video Folder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="113"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="VideoFolderTextBox" Margin="306,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True"/>

    <ItemsControl x:Name="FileItemsControl" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:VideoFile">
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5" Padding="5">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" />
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Output}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <Button x:Name="SelectFFmpegButton" Content="Select FFprobe" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="98"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="FFmpegTextBox" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="150,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsReadOnly="True"/>

    <Button x:Name="StartButton" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: а класс-то в каком пространстве имён лежит у вас?

Comment: @PavelMayorov в avalonvidprocapp

Comment: Почти все WPF подобные проекты обновляют данные для XAML только после успешной пересборки проекта. Уберите все ошибки (если они есть), и пересоберите проект в студии, потом пробуйте добавить все это. Если не поможет, можете удалить временные файлы проекта (папка `obj` и `bin`), и также пересобрать проект.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не помогло, на WPF было легче с указанием источника откуда брать инфу, а вот в avalonia что-то все через Ж у меня идет

Comment: Зачем вы туда залезли, я не пойму) Для десктопа спокойно отрабатывает WPF как положено, ну а кросплатформ - новомодный MAUI. Как бы, смысла брать что-то стороннее, я лично не вижу, но как знать, зависит конечно от задач и требований. Ну а так, сверяйте все Namespace, смотрите лог сборки, список ошибок, поищите данную ошибку на GitHub, может там будет что полезное. На данном моменте, из того, что вы показали, все выглядит хорошо (даже в документации [аналогично](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/templates/data-templates) написанному), из-за чего сказать в чем там проблема, трудно...

Comment: Хм, а попробуйте `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:avalonvidprocapp"` переписать на `xmlns:local="using:avalonvidprocapp"`